# As soon as I put in a "data-client-token", the PayPal button refuses draw. Any idea why?

Tags: javascript, paypal

In my page I have

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=REDACTED&enable-funding=venmo&currency=AUD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
```

As soon as I put in a data-client-token, e.g.

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=REDACTED&enable-funding=venmo&currency=AUD" data-client-token="DEPOSIT" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
```

the button refuses to draw. Any clues as to why? According to the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/#client-token), this additional markup is permitted.

**LATER**

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="smart-button-container">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&enable-funding=venmo&currency=AUD" 
    data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',

        },

        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
          // Set up the transaction
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                value: '0.01'
              }
            }]
          });
        },

        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function (orderData) {

            // Full available details
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

            // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
            const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            element.innerHTML = '';
            element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');

          });
        },

        onError: function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

That works. However, if one puts `data-client-token="DEPOSIT"` into the   `<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&enable-funding=venmo&currency=AUD"  data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>` line, it doesn't draw.

Comment: Does it occur in sandbox? Can't really be of any help when you redact your client ID and it can't be reproduced

Comment: sandbox? Hmmm ... good question. Redacted because well hey who needs to know my client id?

Comment: Anyone trying to answer this question who needs a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, working on it

Answer (score 0):

(Initially I tried with https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client but it seems that editor removes the data-client-token; have to load an actual .html file to reproduce )

From what I can tell of how data-client-token is parsed, its purpose is specific for the sort of client token you get back from the pre-page-load API call [for an Advanced integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/#link-generateclienttoken). The parameter is not meant to be used for anything other than that...